# Selenium pausing with WebDriverWait without using .until()?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to use `WebDriverWait` to pause without calling `.until()`?

something like this

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
#some code
wait
#some other code
```

I'm trying to use it that way and it doesn't seem to do anything. I don't have a target for `wait.until()` to wait for. I just want to slow down how fast it clicks through things.

It feels like it's running so fast it's throwing an engine belt and skipping iterations through my list.

I'm adding `time.sleep(2)` in some key places, but figure I'm defining `wait` so why can't I just use that?

My code exectutes fine if I debug and step through it, even if I step out of whole functions. It's just when I let it off the leash that it seems to forget to process some items in the list.

Comment: wait is a polling loop.... so it checks for certain conditions to be met and ignores certain exceptions thrown.  It only waits as long as it takes to meet the condition or the timeout period if it hasn't been met.  For your use case, you'd want a sleep though really you just need better designed explicit webdriverwaits to handle whatever is causing the skipped iterations.  (to directly answer your question, just return false to the until... but that's more overhead than using a sleep)